# ActionMailer emails "sent" in development.log, but not received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm having problems *actually* sending via ActionMailer in development, on my localhost, with **Rails 2.3.2** and **Ruby 1.8.6**. The development.log shows that it has "sent" the email with no errors, but the email is not received. I have tried multiple email addresses for sending and receiving and have tried multiple configs and plugins, but cannot get the email to send. Any help would be much appreciated - I feel like I'm dancing around a bunch of versions of solutions for different versions of rails and ruby and can't nail it down. I would much appreciate any comments. Thanks!

Plugins:

- action mailer optional tls
- smtp_tls

Different email configs:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, #works in ruby 1.8.7 and above
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'example.com',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'testacct',
    :password => 'secret'
  }
```

---

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :tls => :true,
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'testacct@gmail.com',
    :password => 'secret'
    #:enable_starttls_auto => true # for rails >= 2.2 && ruby >= 1.8.7
  }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = :true #try to force sending in development 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = :true 
  config.action_mailer.default_charset = "utf-8"
```

---

Development.log:

```
Sent mail to sa23kdj@trash2009.com

Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2009 00:27:06 -0800
From: Test Email Acct <testacct@gmail.com>
To: sa23kdj@trash2009.com
Subject: Signup
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_4b2b3cda9088_634334302a5b7


--mimepart_4b2b3cda9088_634334302a5b7
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://ww=
w.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang=3D'en' xml:lang=3D'en' xmlns=3D'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>=

  <head>
    <meta content=3D'text/html;charset=3DUTF-8' http-equiv=3D'content-typ=
e' />
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome Email
    <p>
      user name:
      lfglkdfgklsdf
      activation link:
      http://localhost:3000/login
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

--mimepart_4b2b3cda9088_634334302a5b7--
```

Comment: Check if those are being marked as spam.

Comment: Thanks guys, not sure what happened (maybe something with the smtp server), but it works today with the same exact code. guh.

Comment: I just now restarted the rails console to get it working. That could have been it.

Answer (score 14):

Put the following in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

It will override the settings in `config/environment.rb`

Also for rails `2.X` you'll need to setup:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,  
  :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port           => 587,
  :domain         => "domain.com",
  :user_name      => "username@domain.com",
  :password       => "secret_passsword",
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `raise_delivery_errors = true`. That helped me get closer to identifying the error, which was that I had only put the "**name**" part in the value of `user_name`, not the full email address "**name@example.com**". Having put the full email address, the email sent! Note: I did *not* need to set `perform_deliveries = true`. And I'm running Rails 3.1.0 at this time.

Comment: So I am having this exact same problem. No it is not in spam, yes the messages confirms sent, and yes I also have raise delivery errors and perform deliveries set to true. Did we decide it just eventually magically worked? No clear answer here...

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `true` and not `:true`.

```
:tls => true
...
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true #try to force sending in development 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: Not sure, but are they interchangeable? I also tried using "true" instead of ":true".

Comment: They may be interchangeable, as the library is probably just checking if they're not `nil` and not `false`.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone faces this problem, set "config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true" in development.rb in your environments folder and try sending mail again. This should raise whatever error is being encountered.

Sometimes in line 8 of smtp_tls.rb , the check_auth_args method accepts only 2 arguments : user and secret. Remove the 'authtype' argument if you see it and try again. Should work.

Comment: Great tip! Also worth noting that if you're specifying some parts of your config elsewhere, ex. using [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), which I'd highly recommend, make sure you wrap any values that could contain special characters in single quotes.